# ZF2 - Multiple entities in a single form

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am working on a shopping checkout page which requires:

1. OrderPerson
2. PersonAddress (delivery)
3. Order (notes, time etc. not all items are on the form at present to keep it simple)

I have more or less worked out how to put this together however it requires some tidying up.

My form looks as follows:[image: Checkout Form]

To make the forms play nicely together I have setup a CheckoutForm that includes the OrderPerson, PersonAddress and Order Fieldsets:

```
<?php
namespace MyCart\Form;

use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

class CheckoutForm extends Form
{

    public function __construct(
        InputFilterInterface $orderFilter,
        InputFilterInterface $orderPersonFilter,
        InputFilterInterface $personAddressFilter,
        $name = null,
        $options = array()
    ) {
        parent::__construct('checkout', $options);

        $this->orderFilter = $orderFilter;
        $this->orderPersonFilter = $orderPersonFilter;
        $this->personAddressFilter = $personAddressFilter;
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->add(
            [
                'name' => 'csrfcheck',
                'type' => 'csrf'
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name' => 'order',
                'type' => OrderFieldset::class,
                'options' => [
                    'use_as_base_fieldset' => true
                ]
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name' => 'order-person',
                'type' => OrderPersonFieldset::class,
                'options' => [
                    'use_as_base_fieldset' => true
                ]
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name' => 'person-address',
                'type' => PersonAddressFieldset::class,
                'options' => [
                    'use_as_base_fieldset' => true
                ]
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'submit',
                'type'       => 'submit',
                'attributes' => [
                    'value' => 'Update',
                    'class' => 'form-element'
                ]
            ]
        );

        $this->getInputFilter()->add($this->orderFilter, 'order');
        $this->getInputFilter()->add($this->orderPersonFilter, 'order-person');
        $this->getInputFilter()->add($this->personAddressFilter, 'person-address');

    }
}
```

The Checkout Form has a factory:

```
<?php
namespace MyCart\Form\Factory;

use MyCart\Form\CheckoutForm;
use MyCart\InputFilter\OrderFilter;
use MyCart\InputFilter\OrderPersonFilter;
use MyCart\InputFilter\PersonAddressFilter;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class CheckoutFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create service
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $inputFilter =  $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('InputFilterManager');

        return new CheckoutForm(
            $inputFilter->get(OrderFilter::class),
            $inputFilter->get(OrderPersonFilter::class),
            $inputFilter->get(PersonAddressFilter::class)
        );
    }
}
```

AS you can see the Checkout Form references the three input filters that are all constructed in the same manner. I have the OrderPerson fieldset here as a reference:

```
<?php
namespace MyCart\Form;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject;
use MyCart\Entity\OrderPerson;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;

class OrderPersonFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $objectManager
     * @param OrderPerson $orderPrototype
     * @param null $name
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function __construct(
        ObjectManager   $objectManager,
        OrderPerson     $orderPrototype,
        $name           = null,
        $options        = array()
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $options);

        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineObject($objectManager));
        $this->setObject($orderPrototype);
    }

    public function init()
    {

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'id',
                'type'       => 'hidden',
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'name'       => 'rbu_user_id',
                'type'       => 'hidden',
            ]
        );

        $this->add(
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'name' => 'email',
                'attributes' => [
                    'class'     => 'form-control',
                    'required' => 'required',
                ],
                'options' => [
                    'label'  => 'Email Address',
                    'instructions' => 'Please enter your email address',
                ],
            ]
        );

        //etc...




    }
}
```

On execution of the form the CheckoutController is called and this is where I am unsure of what to do or how to save the various objects, this is what I have so far:

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        //Pre check stuff here

        //Start the form processing
        $prg = $this->prg();

        if ($prg instanceof Response) {

            return $prg;

        } elseif ($prg === false) {

            //If logged in
            if ( $this->authService->hasIdentity()) {

                //Update the OrderPerson entity
                $user_id = $this->identity()->getId();
                $userObject = $this->userService->find($user_id);
                $orderPersonEntity = new OrderPerson();
                $orderPersonEntity->setRbuUser($userObject);
                $orderPersonEntity->setFirstname($userObject->getFirstname());
                $orderPersonEntity->setSurname($userObject->getSurname());
                $this->checkoutForm->bind($orderPersonEntity);

                //Update the person address entity
                $personAddress = new PersonAddress();
                $personAddress->setAddress1($userObject->getAddress1());
                $personAddress->setAddress2($userObject->getAddress2());
                $this->checkoutForm->bind($personAddress);

                //Update the order entity

            }

            return new ViewModel(
                array(
                    'cart' => $cart,
                    'form' => $this->checkoutForm
                )
            );

        }

        $this->checkoutForm->setData($prg);

        if (!$this->checkoutForm->isValid()) {
            return new ViewModel(
                array(
                    'cart' => $cart,
                    'form' => $this->checkoutForm
                )
            );
        }



        $checkoutObject = $this->checkoutForm->getData();

        die(var_dump($checkoutObject));
```

Dumping the result here outputs only the person address object:

```
object(MyCart\Entity\PersonAddress)[1177]
  private 'id' => null
  private 'address1' => string 'xx' (length=2)
  private 'address2' => string 'xx' (length=2)
  private 'region' => null
  private 'postCode' => string 'xx' (length=2)
  private 'city' => string 'xx' (length=2)
  private 'country' => string 'xx' (length=2)
  private 'created' => null
  private 'modified' => null
  private 'orderPerson' => null
```

So my question is simply, is this the right thinking and how do I complete this so that I can save the three entities in a single go?

Comment: Check out the [`AggregateHydrator`](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.aggregate.html#aggregatehydrator)

Comment: Sometimes building forms with entities connected to them is really painful so the [Form Annotation Builder](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/zend-framework-2-step-by-step-build-form-using-annotation-builder/) helps.